# Molex 5556 vs. 44476 Terminals for ATX / EPS connectors

Tags: connector, atx, terminal

I'm looking into terminating a custom-length power supply extension cable to make everything look nice / fit in an awkward case. While researching parts I noticed that the [EPS12V v2.0 specification](https://web.archive.org/web/20061114023234/http://www.psui.com/1upower/pdf/892_ref.pdf) states that Molex 44476-1111 or equivalent contacts be used but it also says that the Baseboard Power Connector should use the Molex 39-01-2240 housing. The housing is from the 5557 Mini-Fit Jr series and [it specifies that 5556-series terminals](http://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/ps/PS-5556-001.pdf) be used rather than the 44476-series that EPS12V states.

Are the 5556-series terminals roughly compatible with the 44476-series? If not, should I use 44476 since that's what is in the spec?

The dimensions of the two are similar but not exact (data sheets for the [5556-series](http://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/039000077_sd.pdf) and [44476-series](http://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/444763111_sd.pdf)). I noticed that the 5556 is tin-coated-brass whereas the 44476 are tin-coated-copper-alloy. Maybe that's the big difference?

Comment: Brass is a copper alloy too.

Comment: I would use the contacts that Molex recommends for the specified housing.